# How to remove date from Calendar.app dock tile?

Tags: macos, dock

I want to remove the current date from the Calendar.app dock tile. I have changed its icons (by replacing the icns-files inside the .app) however it still shows the current date over the icon. How can I remove this date?

[image: Calendar.app with current date]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible as I've done some own research and found out that within the Calendar.app there's a "CalDockTileView" class which calls the "drawDockTileInRect"  method to update the "monthStringAttributes" and the "dateStringAttributes" and has it "rotateByDegrees"

Comment: Can I change/recompile these myself? How did you find them?

Comment: I'm not getting involved in recompiling other apps as I look at it as part of a hack which I keep distance; I found it by searching thru all the services involved and then by looking deeper into the Calendar file within the "/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS" folder which is the main executable file for the Calendar.app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This is an untested (edit: now tested by OP) modification of the Calendar.app, you may do it at your on risk. Back up your computer to an external drive first.

Doing the following will stop the Calendar dock icon from having that date overlay.

1. If we right-click on `Calendar` in the Applications folder, an option comes up that says "Show Package Contents". That will reveal some (not all) of the inner workings of the Calendar app.
2. If you navigate to `_CodeSignature` and then `CodeResources`, you will find some of the resources the Calendar app uses to operate. Searching for `dock` inside that file reveals data keys including
   `<key>Resources/Calendar.docktileplugin/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources</key>`. This points us to a file that may well control the Calendar icon (notice `Calendar.docktileplugin`).
3. So let's go there. Follow the file tree: back up one step, go to resources, and find the `Calendar.docktileplugin` folder. Deleting this folder will stop the Calendar app from automatically putting the current date on top of your calendar icon (**Edit** you might want to save a backup of this plugin as I mention in `Edit 2` below).

There you have what I believe is the solution to your problem.

**Edit:** If the Calendar app crashes on launch, try deleting the original key (from step 2). If that doesn't work, my solution might not be so good.

**Edit 2:** Save a backup of the Calendar.docktileplugin folder (like maybe on your Desktop) before deleting it and remember where it went so you can always put it back if the Calendar app just crashes or if you want to restore the Calendar icon to original anytime.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It did indeed seem like just deleting the `Calendar.docktileplugin` folder did the job. The overlay is no longer present on the dock icon.

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen Nice! Just let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Well, ideally I would like to change the rotation and font of the actual date, to have it match the design, but I think that'll require me to decompile the actual Calendar.app and do changes inside the actual code. That might be overkilling it a bit. :)

Comment: @MadsOhmLarsen you could consider making a program to change the icon of the Calendar app every day, but glad to help with your question.